# Are there any regular nonstop flights between Washington DC and Vancouver Canada?

Tags: air-travel, vancouver, washington-dc

While I have heard there are nonstop flights between one of the 3 Washington DC airports and Vancouver (YVR) I have never in practice been able to find one.  Are there any regular nonstop flights between Washington DC and Vancouver Canada?

Answer (score 4):

There is a seasonal flight between IAD (Washington Dulles) and YVR (Vancouver International) by United Airlines/Air Canada. Here's an [example search](http://www.kayak.com/flights/WAS-YVR/2014-06-03-flexible/2014-06-17-flexible) on Kayak.

Comment: Thanks, is there some way to find out what the season is for this type of flight?  I suppose I've never found one to date because the date ranges I've searched were not "in season".  If I knew the season with direct flights I may arrange my travel differently.

Comment: @Stimy These days, as timetables are either not published or only apply for [a few weeks ahead](http://www.united.com/CMS/UADocuments/pdfs/timetable.pdf), you need to use trial and error with a tool which lets you search flights regardless of seat availability. I asked http://matrix.itasoftware.com/ to return nonstop flights for a 28-day trip beginning any time in the month after May 28, ignoring availability. The only nonstop, UA1150 (codeshare AC5309/AC5389), operates from 5 June to 18 August, inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

[Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Washington-Dulles/Vancouver) says that united offers direct connections.